# Request.Form error inside Windows Universal WebView

Tags: forms, post, null, win-universal-app, request.form

I have windows 10 UWP App, which uses Webview for search & Listings.

It works fine except it gets error wherever there is

Request.form

Data Posted from previous page.

The error is

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzPDm.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the Problem, I was opening a new webview every time a user clicks a link. I commented that piece of code now its working fine.

Thanks